# ResolvTimeout exception while adding a gem source

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I am getting a ResolveTimeout exception while adding a gem source.  What does that mean?

Here's the result of `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:

  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/NSDont/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
     - /Users/NSDont/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => []
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/NSDont/.rvm/bin
     - node_modules/.bin
     - /Users/NSDont/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

Here's the result of `gem source`:

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***
```

As you can see, I don't have any sources.  But when I try to add one:

`gem sources -a http://mirrors.aliyun.com/rubygems/ -V --debug`

I get a ResolvTimeout exception:

```
NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:168 - LoadError
Exception `Resolv::ResolvTimeout' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:687 - Resolv::ResolvTimeout
Exception `Resolv::ResolvTimeout' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:687 - Resolv::ResolvTimeout
Exception `Resolv::ResolvTimeout' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:687 - Resolv::ResolvTimeout
Exception `Resolv::ResolvTimeout' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:687 - Resolv::ResolvTimeout
Exception `Resolv::ResolvTimeout' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:687 - Resolv::ResolvTimeout
Exception `Resolv::ResolvTimeout' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:687 - Resolv::ResolvTimeout
```

What does the ResolvEimtout exception mean?

Run `gem sources --add https://rubygems.org -V --debug` still error:

```
NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:168 - LoadError
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/NSDont/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:300 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - /Users/NSDont/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443/specs.4.8
GET https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLErrorWaitReadable' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182 - read would block
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLErrorWaitReadable' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182 - read would block
Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLErrorWaitReadable' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182 - read would block
Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLErrorWaitReadable' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182 - read would block
Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLErrorWaitReadable' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182 - read would block
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `gem source` using this command,

```
 $ gem sources --add https://rubygems.org
```

Comment: The OP has tried to do that, but is getting an exception.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I think the error is show at the bottom of the post.  I've just edited it to (I hope) make the question more clear.

Comment: See what is your `openssl` version using this command `$ openssl version` and update with latest `openssl` vesrion and try again and let me know